# Merge columns values within the same dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello I have a dataframe such as

```
  >>> tab
   COL1                     COL2 COL3 COL4    COL5
0    G1        S_-__1Canis_lupus    A    B    SEQ1
1    G1          S_+__2Elpah_bis    C    D  SEQ4.1
2    G1       S_-__3Felis_cattus  NaN  NaN  SEQA.B
3    G1       S_-__4Felis_cattus  NaN  NaN  SEQA.B
4    G1  S-BICs_-__5Felis_cattus    E    F  SEQA.A
5    G1       S_+__6Felis_cattus  NaN  NaN  SEQA.A
6    G1       S_-__7Felis_cattus  NaN  NaN  SEQA.A
7    G1  S-BICs_-__8Felis_cattus    L    P  SEQA.B
8    G1       S_-__9Felis_cattus    K    L  SEQA.A
9    G2      S_+__10Felis_cattus    M    N  SEQA.A
10   G2       S_-__11Lupus_lupus  NaN  NaN    SEQ3
```

and the idea is within each `COL1 groups` to focus on value in `COL2` that contain the pattern : `-BICs`

then fill all `COL3` and `COL4` values that are `NaN` with the same `COL5` value as the one that contain the `-BICs` pattern

exemple :

in line4 `S-BICs_-__5Felis_cattus` has a `-BICs`pattern, its `COL5` = `SEQA.A`

Within `G1`

**S_-__3Felis_cattus** and **S_-__4Felis_cattus** have `NaN` values in `COL3` and `COL4` and have the same `COL5` value. Then I put the `COL3` and `COL4` values of `S-BICs_-__5Felis_cattus`
:

```
   >>> tab
   COL1                     COL2 COL3 COL4    COL5
0    G1        S_-__1Canis_lupus    A    B    SEQ1
1    G1          S_+__2Elpah_bis    C    D  SEQ4.1
2    G1       S_-__3Felis_cattus  NaN  NaN  SEQA.B
3    G1       S_-__4Felis_cattus  NaN  NaN  SEQA.B
4    G1  S-BICs_-__5Felis_cattus    E    F  SEQA.A
5    G1       S_+__6Felis_cattus    E    F  SEQA.A
6    G1       S_-__7Felis_cattus    E    F  SEQA.A
7    G1  S-BICs_-__8Felis_cattus    L    P  SEQA.B
8    G1       S_-__9Felis_cattus    K    L  SEQA.A
9    G2      S_+__10Felis_cattus    M    N  SEQA.A
10   G2       S_-__11Lupus_lupus  NaN  NaN    SEQ3
```

and same for the `S-BICs_-__8Felis_cattus where NaN are transformed to`L`and`P`

```
   >>> tab
   COL1                     COL2 COL3 COL4    COL5
0    G1        S_-__1Canis_lupus    A    B    SEQ1
1    G1          S_+__2Elpah_bis    C    D  SEQ4.1
2    G1       S_-__3Felis_cattus    L    P  SEQA.B
3    G1       S_-__4Felis_cattus    L    P  SEQA.B
4    G1  S-BICs_-__5Felis_cattus    E    F  SEQA.A
5    G1       S_+__6Felis_cattus    E    F  SEQA.A
6    G1       S_-__7Felis_cattus    E    F  SEQA.A
7    G1  S-BICs_-__8Felis_cattus    L    P  SEQA.B
8    G1       S_-__9Felis_cattus    K    L  SEQA.A
9    G2      S_+__10Felis_cattus    M    N  SEQA.A
10   G2       S_-__11Lupus_lupus  NaN  NaN    SEQ3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `where` the col2 `str.contains` the pattern to repalce all the rows that does not contains the pattern with nan. Then [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#transformation) by col1 and col5 and get `first` (to get the non nan value if any). Finally, `fillna` the original data like:

```
tab[['COL3','COL4']] = (tab[['COL3','COL4']]
                           .fillna(tab[['COL3','COL4']]
                                      .where(tab['COL2'].str.contains('-BICs'))
                                      .groupby([tab['COL1'], tab['COL5']])
                                      .transform('first'))
                       )
print (tab)
   COL1                     COL2 COL3 COL4    COL5
0    G1        S_-__1Canis_lupus    A    B    SEQ1
1    G1          S_+__2Elpah_bis    C    D  SEQ4.1
2    G1       S_-__3Felis_cattus    L    P  SEQA.B
3    G1       S_-__4Felis_cattus    L    P  SEQA.B
4    G1  S-BICs_-__5Felis_cattus    E    F  SEQA.A
5    G1       S_+__6Felis_cattus    E    F  SEQA.A
6    G1       S_-__7Felis_cattus    E    F  SEQA.A
7    G1  S-BICs_-__8Felis_cattus    L    P  SEQA.B
8    G1       S_-__9Felis_cattus    K    L  SEQA.A
9    G2      S_+__10Felis_cattus    M    N  SEQA.A
10   G2       S_-__11Lupus_lupus  NaN  NaN    SEQ3
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, what about something like:

```
reference = tab.iloc[tab["COL2"].str.contains("-BICs"),:].rename(columns = {"COL2":"R_COL2","COL3":"R_COL3","COL4":"R_COL4"})
table = pd.merge(table,reference, how='left')

table.iat[table["COL3"].isnull(), 2] = table.iloc[table["COL3"].isnull(), 6]
table.iat[table["COL3"].isnull(), 3] = table.iloc[table["COL3"].isnull(), 7]

table = table[["COL1","COL2","COL3","COL4","COL5"]]
```

I didn't try it, but the idea would be to do something similar.